# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query') InertiaJS, React, Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I have a problem making a search feature for my project. I facing this error **"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')"** which is already defined. i don't have any experience using inertia,

```
const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
  name: '',
});
```

this code above is the default code provided by laravel + react + inertiajs which is defined automatically, but when I try to define a new variable for my search feature like the code bellow.

```
const { query, setQuery, get} = useForm({
    query: '',
});
```

then I got this error
**"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'query')"**, im start thinking useForm() helper cant be use more than on 1 times on a page. so I delete this code.

```
const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
  name: '',
});
```

and the result still the same.

also, one more thing, as u can see in code bellow

```
const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
  name: '',
});
```

**post** method is defined to do a post request to API. which is don't understand. when i read the inertia docs we can use the method by importing Inertia like code bellow.

```
import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia'

Inertia.get(url, data, options)
Inertia.post(url, data, options)
Inertia.put(url, data, options)
Inertia.patch(url, data, options)
Inertia.delete(url, options)
Inertia.reload(options) // Uses the current URL enter code here
```

but if i implemented the code above im facing error like **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')**

let's say i want to trigger the api request when any change in the input happen

```
const onHandleChange = (event) => {
    setData(event.target.name, event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value);
    Inertia.get(route('permission.search'),data);
};
```

please keep on mind , this is my first time using react and inertia so I don't have any idea about this.

this is my whole code :

```
import React, { useEffect , useState } from 'react';
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout';
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError';
import InputLabel from '@/Components/InputLabel';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Components/PrimaryButton';
import Flash from '@/Components/Flash';
import TextInput from '@/Components/TextInput';
import Paginator from '@/Components/Paginator';
import { Head, Link, useForm, Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';

export default function Permission (props){
    const { data, setData, post, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
    name: '',
});

const { query, setQuery, get} = useForm({
    query: '',
});

const onHandleChange = (event) => {
    setData(event.target.name, event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value);
};

const searchChange = (event) => {
    setQuery(event.target.query, event.target.type === 'checkbox' ? event.target.checked : event.target.value);
};


const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    post(route('permission.store'));
};

const submitQuery = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    get(route('permission.search'));
};

console.log(query)

return (
    <AuthenticatedLayout auth={props.auth} errors={props.errors}>
    <div className="w-full lg:max-w-6xl mt-6 px-6 py-4 bg-white shadow-md overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg">        
        { props.flash.message !== null ? <Flash message = {props.flash.message}/> : <div></div>}    
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <div>
                <InputLabel forInput="name" value="Permission" />

                <TextInput
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    value={data.name}
                    className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                    autoComplete="name"
                    isFocused={true}
                    handleChange={onHandleChange}
         
                />

                <InputError message={errors.name} className="mt-2" />


                <PrimaryButton className="ml-4" processing={processing}>
                    Submit
                </PrimaryButton>


            </div>

        </form>

        <hr></hr>

        <form>
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={submitQuery}>
                    <InputLabel forInput="query" value="Search" />
                    <TextInput
                        type="text"
                        name="query"
                        value={query.query}
                        className="m-2 input input-bordered w-full"
                        autoComplete="query"
                        handleChange={searchChange}
                    />
                </form>

            
            </div>
        </form>

        <div className="overflow-x-auto">
            <table className="table table-zebra w-full">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Guard</th>
                        <th>Created At</th>
                        <th>Updated At</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {props.permission.data && props.permission.data.length > 0 ? props.permission.data.map((permission, i) => {
                    return(
                    <tr key={i}>
                        <th>{i+1}</th>
                        <td>{permission.name}</td>
                        <td>{permission.guard_name}</td>
                        <td>{permission.created_at}</td>
                        <td>{permission.updated_at}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div className="badge badge-outline">
                                <Link method="get" href={route('permission.edit')} data={{ id: permission.id }} as="button">
                                    edit
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                            <div className="badge badge-outline">
                                <Link method="delete" href={route('permission.destroy')} data={{ id: permission.id }} as="button">
                                    delete
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    )
                    }):<p>Permission Coming Soon!</p>
                }

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center'>
            <Paginator meta={props.permission.meta} />
        </div>
    </div>

    </AuthenticatedLayout>
    
)
}
```

Please help me to figure this out. Thank you in advance

Comment: In first step you are just destructing the object and getting all variables that useForm is returning; what I'm guessing is that there shall be no query variable returned from useForm

Comment: so i need to make new variable without useForm?

Comment: Yes react useState hook is what you need: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: i have 1 problem if i dont use the useForm i cant use the get method which i explain above

Comment: You said it works fine when you use it shown in the first step; it gives all the variables from useForm. Then using the useState hook set the query variable ```const [query, setQuery] = useState({query: ''});```

Comment: @AliRaza i got new error Warning: A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.